# KDB+/Q: Efficient way of padding an irregular list of lists (matrix)

Tags: kdb

given the following list of lists:

```
q)m
  1 1
  1 1 
  1 1 1
```

What is an effective method of producing a regular matrix (padding empty spaces with 0) as shown below:

```
q)m
  1 1 0
  1 1 0
  1 1 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is the below:

```
q)m:(1 1;1 1;1 1 1)
q){x,'(max[c]-c:count each x)#'0}m
1 1 0
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Just find the difference in length between the longest row and the other rows and append that number of zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

The iterative conditional statement below should also work, where a 0 is appended to the end of each row until it reaches the length of the longest row.

```
q)m:(1 1;1 1;1 1 1)
q){{x,0}/[{(max count each m)>(count x)};x]}'[m]
1 1 0
1 1 0
1 1 1
```